# Compare Multiple Pairs of Docs

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am a professor in an English department, and my composition students often write multiple drafts of their essays. I use Word 2010 to track their changes.

I discovered VBA code on another site (located [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/34455e4b-5238-42ae-acaf-1cf7084b0bc1/macro-to-compare-word-documents-and-only-produce-output-if-discrepancy-is-found?forum=worddev)). I created a new macro. It prompts me correctly for the base, new, and comparison folders, but the output is null.

I have the files in both the base and new folders named identically and saved in .doc format. I also set the trust center options in Word to 1) enable all macros and 2) trust access to the VBA project object model.

```
Sub CompareAllFiles()
    Dim strFolderA As String
    Dim strFolderB As String
    Dim strFolderC As String
    Dim strFileSpec As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim objDocA As Word.Document
    Dim objDocB As Word.Document
    Dim objDocC As Word.Document
    strFolderA = InputBox("Enter path to base documents:")
    strFolderB = InputBox("Enter path to new documents:")
    strFolderC = InputBox("Enter path for document comparisons to be saved:")
    strFileSpec = "*.doc"
    strFileName = Dir(strFolderA & strFileSpec)
    Do While strFileName <> vbNullString
        Set objDocA = Documents.Open(strFolderA & strFileName)
        Set objDocB = Documents.Open(strFolderB & strFileName)
        Application.CompareDocuments _
            OriginalDocument:=objDocA, _
            RevisedDocument:=objDocB, _
            Destination:=wdCompareDestinationNew
        objDocA.Close
        objDocB.Close
        Set objDocC = ActiveDocument
        objDocC.SaveAs FileName:=strFolderC & strFileName
        objDocC.Close SaveChanges:=False
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop
    Set objDocA = Nothing
    Set objDocB = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you and your students are using Word 2010 then the extension would most likely be `.docx`:

```
strFileSpec = "*.docx"
```

Have you tried running the code step-by-step with the VBA debugger, to see what is the exact point of failure? See [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) (under the section entitled **Stepping Through Code**) for a simple introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Some kind VBA guru figured it out for me: I need to enter a \ at the end of the folder paths. Without the final backslash, the script was not able to locate the folders, and thus it wasn't processing any files. After adding the final \ to all three folder paths, the code ran perfectly.

As a bonus, the code processes both .doc and .docx files. I thought I was going to have to convert all my .docx files to .doc before processing, but the code is smarter than that.

Eureka!

Comment: Please mark this as the answer to the question (with the outlined checkmark next to the answer).